# lftp how to upload everything new inside a folder but not the folder itself

Tags: linux, ftp, webserver, lftp

I have this script in the a Pipeline:

```
lftp -c
"
  set ftp:ssl-force true;
  set ssl:verify-certificate false;
  open -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASS $FTP_HOST;
  cd remote-folder;
  mirror -R -e -v -n ./dist ./;
"
```

It's working, but I don't wish to upload the `dist` folder itself, I only want to upload what's inside of it using mirror (since I just want newer/different files).

So in this case, I want everything inside the local `dist` folder to be inside the remote `remote-folder` folder (don't want to upload the folder itself).

Already tried `mirror -R -e -v -n ./dist/* ./` but:

> mirror: Access failed: .../dist/*: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify `dist/.` as the source:

```
lftp> mirror -R -v localsrc/. remotedst/
```

lftp will then attempt to upload into `remotedst/./` which is just the same `remotedst`.

Also works for local copies:

```
$ cp -r -v src/. dst/
```